# How do I create a dashboard launcher shortcut without gksu for the Samba Server Configuration Tool in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity?

Tags: 18.04, unity, shortcuts, gksu

How do I create a dashboard launcher shortcut for the Samba Server Configuration Tool 1.2.63 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity [and without gksu]?  I am used to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In 16.04 LTS, I have a system-config-samba.desktop file located in /usr/share/applications.

This .desktop file contains *Exec=gksu system-config-samba*

When run, a password pop-up box appears the root password is entered. From my understanding, Ubuntu 18.04 got rid of gksu entirely, so how do I create a dashboard shortcut to the Samba Server Configuration Tool without gksu?  If I create the shortcut in the same manner as for 16.04 but on 18.04,the samba config tool just won't open. If I remove the gksu from the icon's command box entry, it also will not open, nor does the password box appear.

I can still run *sudo system-config-samba* from the command line, however I just do not have the human memory capacity to remember all these [numerous] Linux commands. I would like a clickable icon in the launcher or the dashboard.  This problem doesn't just apply to the Samba config tool, but really any .desktop shortcut file which previously needed gksu run along with its executable name.

Thanks!

Comment: Currently, `pkexec` serves that goal. A little more convoluted: it requires to set up a policy file for the application (file that indicates the permissions of the program). I don't know the details, but at least this gives you a pointer.

Comment: Just for your information: system-config-samba was removed from the repository in newer versions of Ubuntu and most other distros because programmatically it is considered a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-samba/+bug/1740419

Comment: Unable to find a simplistic solution and in a timely fashion, I ultimately installed the old gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb package and its dependencies.